# renaming a variable in ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the relevant html:

```
<ng-include src="'app/views/order.html'"></ng-include>
```

Attached to the scope this `ng-include` is nested in is a trade variable. The trade variable looks like:

```
var trade = {
    order: {}
}
```

The problem is that order.html is expecting an order variable not a `trade.order`

How can I call the `ng-include` and pass in `trade.order` as `order`?

Answer (score 2):

ng-include reads the variables within the global scope. You cannot use that. It won't work.

And do not use `onload` because it litters the global scope.

The cleaner solution is to make [a new generic directive](http://tech.fongmun.com/post/131863914487/scoping-variables-in-ng-include-without-ng-repeat)

Here's the ideal usage:

```
<div ng-include-template="'app/views/order.html'" ng-include-variables="{ order: trade.order }"></div>
```

The directive is:

```
.directive(
  'ngIncludeTemplate'
  () ->
    {
      templateUrl: (elem, attrs) -> attrs.ngIncludeTemplate
      restrict: 'A'
      scope: {
        'ngIncludeVariables': '&'
      }
      link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        vars = scope.ngIncludeVariables()
        for key, value of vars
          scope[key] = value
    }
)
```

You can see that the directive doesn't use the global scope. Instead, it reads the object from ng-include-variables and add those members to its own local scope.

I hope this helps. It's clean and generic.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question yesterday.

Same answer: use a directive with isolated scope

[Multiple ngIncludes with Different controls visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883326/multiple-ngincludes-with-different-controls-visible/28883585#28883585)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a new directive:

```
  angular.module('MyApp').directive('includeTemplate', directive);

  function directive() {
      return {
          templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
              return attrs.includeTemplate;
          },
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              'includeVariables': '&'
          },
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
              var vars = scope.includeVariables();
              Object.keys(vars).forEach(function(key) {
                  scope[key] = vars[key];
              });
          }
      };
  }
```

Here is the usage:

```
<div include-template="'myTemplate.html'" include-variables="{ var: 'myVar' }"></div>
```

Comment: This solution treats your `include-variables` data as static.  It won't track changes that occur in the parent scope.  With a lot more effort, you could actually have 2-directional binding of changes to the `include-variables` data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17876761/361609